# Django Autocomplete Light doesn't return result until process restart

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

When I add a new record in the database, it doesn't appear in the autocomplete results until I restart the python process.  My registry looks like this.

```
    import autocomplete_light

    from .models import Article


    autocomplete_light.register(
        Article,

        choices=Article.objects.published(),

        search_fields=['title', '^id', ],

        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Search by Article Name',
        },
        widget_attrs={
            'class': 'modern-style',
        },
    )
```

Is the choices option cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a class for the registry and setting the request_choices instead of the method above.

```
import autocomplete_light

from apps.abstract.models import PUBLISHED
from .models import Article


class ArticleAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    attrs = {
        'placeholder': 'Search by Article Title',
    }
    search_fields = ['title', '^id', ]
    widget_attrs = {
        'class': 'modern-style',
    }

    def choices_for_request(self):
        """Returns published articles for the request"""
        self.choices = self.choices.filter(status=PUBLISHED)
        return super(ArticleAutocomplete, self).choices_for_request()

autocomplete_light.register(Article, ArticleAutocomplete)
```